# How can I subset or filter data using an arbitrary set of criteria?

Tags: r

I am writing a shiny app, but I can't wrap my head around this one and I am hoping you can help.

Say the user imports in some factors and some data:

```
data<-read.table(text="Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Data
             1 1 1 1 25
             1 1 1 1 15
             1 1 1 2 10
             1 1 1 2 11
             1 1 2 1 30
             1 1 2 1 32
             1 1 2 2 120
             1 1 2 2 123
             1 2 1 1 50
             1 2 1 1 52
             1 2 1 2 100
             1 2 1 2 101
             1 2 2 1 150
             1 2 2 1 152
             1 2 2 2 160
             1 2 2 2 162
             2 1 1 1 5
             2 1 1 1 4
             2 1 1 2 60
             2 1 1 2 62
             2 1 2 1 40
             2 1 2 1 42
             2 1 2 2 130
             2 1 2 2 132
             2 2 1 1 70
             2 2 1 1 72
             2 2 1 2 80
             2 2 1 2 82
             2 2 2 1 90
             2 2 2 1 92
             2 2 2 2 110
             2 2 2 2 111",
             header=T)
```

This data could be anything, any length or number of variables, some number of which might be factors.

I know how to subset out the data for analytics if I want, say, Var1=1 and Var2=2:

```
data[,5][which(data[,1]==1 & data[,2]==2)]
```

or filter

```
filter(data,data[,1]==1 & data[,2]==2)[,5]
```

Now say I want to change it to the data for Var1=1, Var2=2, **and** Var3=2. If I were doing this in script, I could just type another criterion in the filter or the subset. But how would I set it up in the app to be able to filter or subset on an arbitrary number of factors? (Ideally, with base or dplyr.) In the app I can pass in the column numbers for the factors and the data, I just don't know how to set it up to do that regardless of the number of columns the user has selected as factors.

Thanks!

edit....

Answer!

@akrun's excellent answer below, generalized for people like myself! :

```
factors=c(1,2,3,4)
levels_selected=c(1,1,2,1)


data[rowSums(levels_selected[col(data[factors])]==data[factors])==length(levels_selected),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have multiple columns to filter with same value, use `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    filter(Var1 == 1 & if_all(c(Var2, Var3), `==`, 2))
```

-output

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Data
1    1    2    2    1  150
2    1    2    2    1  152
3    1    2    2    2  160
4    1    2    2    2  162
```

---

Also, if these are values specific to certain columns, subset the columns, create a logical vector with `rowSums` after `rep`licating the input values

```
data[rowSums(c(1, 2, 2)[col(data[1:3])] == data[1:3]) == 3,]
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Data
13    1    2    2    1  150
14    1    2    2    1  152
15    1    2    2    2  160
16    1    2    2    2  162
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. That is good to know, but the user might select any combination of any number of factors, so 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 or whatever. edit: also not necessarily 1s and 2s.

Comment: @StevenOuellette those numbers are the values or the column index?

Comment: @StevenOuellette can you check the updated one.  Is that how you pass the values

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this is getting closer I think.In a real file we could potentially have some arbitrary number of columns that are "factors" (in the statistical sense, not necessarily in the R sense). These would be columns of unique numbers (most usually integers, but it is possible it might be, say, four or five temperatures or whatever). So each column

Comment: @StevenOuellette In the code I showed it is a sequence of columns.  But suppose you are passing column  names i..e `nm1 <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")` you can index as well `data[rowSums(c(1, 2, 2)[col(data[nm1])] == data[nm1] == length(nm1),]`

Comment: OK I am going to have to think through this, you have given me a great clue! But yes, the user could choose any column(s) as a factor. Currently, In the app I am passing in the column numbers selected. The problem I am running into is scaling that out from one column to n columns.